# A group object keeps so when passing to the homotopy category?

Tags: model-categories

Let $\mathscr{M}$ be a model category and let $G$ be a group object in $\mathscr{M}$. Then is it also a group object in the homotopy category $\mathsf{Ho}\mathscr{M}$?

Comment: If $G$ is fibrant, then $G\times G$ is also product in the homotopy category and the answer will be yes.

Comment: The problem is that I can't show that the multiplication of $G$ plays well with (right) homotopy.